# Why does the RU consumption reduce so much when using 'ORDER BY' command?

Tags: indexing, sql-order-by, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Document DB and have some confusion how the Order By command work.

Query 1 cost over 4k RU:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts > 0
```

Query 2 cost only 95 RU:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts > 0 ORDER BY c._ts
```

See images:
[image][image]

Please help me explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite Normal and expected, **`Order By`** uses Index and reduces the immense of the query results which will get only the data which are relevant for **`one`** page.

It does use when Index when you say all documents, but it will do the navigate to index tree till it reaches the value. That's the difference. The main point here is the page results which gets only 100 results as shown above

Comment: Without ORDER BY, does the Document DB not to use index? Could you explain more details?

Comment: It does use! When you say query all documents , it will do the navigate to index tree till it reaches the value. That's the difference. The main point here is the page results which gets only 100 results as shown above

Comment: Does it mean that the ORDER BY make the database return first 100 results, without ORDER BY the database need to query all document then return 100 result?

Comment: yeah exactly, if you get all the pages and sums up the RUs sometimes it will be more than the first image RUs

Comment: Thank you for explanation, lately I met some trouble with ORDER BY. Your information is helpful for me.

Comment: Great! glad it helped