# CosmosDB: Is it a good practice to use ORDER BY on the property that is also used in range filter?

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

When I ran the query below on CosmosDB Explorer on Azure portal, several hundreds of RUs was consumed according to Query Stats.

```sql
select * from c where c.name = "john" and c._ts > 0
```

But after I added `order by c._ts` to the query above, only roughly 20 RUs was consumed.
According to [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518670/why-does-the-ru-consumption-reduce-so-much-when-using-order-by-command), this behavior is expected.
(But I don't really understand why range filter is not enough to avoid looking at unnecessary indices)

So is it a good practice to use ORDER BY on the properties that are also used in range filter?

Comment: Interesting question, if it is **always** a good practice then you'd hope the query optimiser would just always do it the efficient way without you having to specify it!

Comment: So it is likely that it is NOT always a good practice.

Comment: If there is no downside then seems like something that should just be done automatically but maybe just not implemented yet? Hopefully someone with better product knowledge than me will clarify...

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that a ORDER BY query will use a range index although it normally does.

The best way to ensure you get a good index hit and thus lower RU consumption consistently is to use a composite index like below, of course adjusting your other properties as needed but you can see the _ts part in there as well.

This information can be found in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-query-performance)

```
{  
        "automatic":true,
        "indexingMode":"Consistent",
        "includedPaths":[  
            {  
                "path":"/*"
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths":[],
        "compositeIndexes":[  
            [  
                {  
                    "path":"/foodGroup",
                    "order":"ascending"
        },
                {  
                    "path":"/_ts",
                    "order":"ascending"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
```